# Page section navigation with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having difficulty solving a scroll problem on a Plugin I'm attempting to write. I'm adding a screenshot, which I hope helps to more easily describe the UI.
[image: UI]

Two things need to happen:

1) When the user scrolls into view, the section becomes 'active' and in turn, the corresponding dot gets the 'active' as well. Each previous dot should remain active while scrolling down. When the user scrolls up, the 'active' class should be removed from the dots. I'm not sure how to solve this? Detect scroll direction? Here's how the current code looks:

```
var _activeSection = function() {

    var setActive;
    setActive = false;

    for (var i = 0, len = sections.length; i < len; i++) {
        // Last section, bottom of window
        if (!setActive && elementInView(sections[i]) && (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            sections[i].classList.add('active'); // Add 'active' class when Section is in view and reaches bottom of the viewport
        } else if (!setActive && elementInView(sections[i])) {
            sections[i].classList.add('active'); // Add 'active' class when Section is in view
            setActive = true;
        } else {
            sections[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
    }

};
```

2) This is the hard part: The scroll progress element (the think vertical bar). Right now, I can't accurately find a way to accurately calculate each increment. Current function:

```
var _setScrollProgress = function() {

    // How many sections are there?
    var sectionCount = (sections.length -1);

    // Metrics
    var scrollProgress = (scrollTop / root.innerHeight) * 100 / sectionCount + '%';// get amount scrolled (in %)

    if (settings.position === 'left' || settings.position === 'right') {
        highlight.style.height = scrollProgress;
    }

};
```

Any ideas and or code snippets would be great. I'm starting to pull my hair out with this thing.

Note: Pure/Vanilla Javascript solutions only please, no jQuery.

Comment: Are you using the scroll Event Listener? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/scroll

Comment: Yes, of course. I haven't included all the code in the Plugin. But yes, absolutely. I am using the scroll event listener and throttling as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of approach I always try to collapse the problem to pure geometry. If you respond to scroll events, you can keep an updated rectangle that maps to the location of the viewport over your document. You can make a list of positional rectangles of each page section.

All you have to do is turn off all your lights, and then light up the one whose midline is closest to your viewport rectangle midline.

You can get rid of all kinds of complexity by using rectangle geometry!

Right, here's a demo - I described the midline thing a bit wrong, turns out it's section top vs. screen midline. Do midline vs. midline, and you're not tracking propery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Little Demo</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 10px;
        }
            .section {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                width: 70%;
                margin: 0 0 10px;
                background: red;
            }
            .section:before {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                padding-top: 60%;
            }
            .guide {
                position: fixed;
                left: 100%;
                top: 50%;
                width: 20%;
                margin-left: -5%;
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .guide li {
                position: relative;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .guide b {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                background: black;
                border-radius: 10px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            .guide b:before {
                position: absolute;
                content: '';
                display: block;
                height: 20px;
                border-left: 2px solid black;
                left: 9px;
                top: -10px;
            }
            .guide li:first-child b:before {
                content: none;
            }
            .guide span {
                position: absolute;
                top: -5px;
                left: -4px;
                margin-left: -120px;
                display: block;
                white-space: nowrap;
                width: 140px;
                text-align: right;
                border: 1px black solid;
                padding: 4px;
                box-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                border-radius: 10px;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            .guide span b {
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
                background: red;
                border: 2px solid black;
            }
            .guide span b:before {
                border-color: red;
                left: 6px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="section">        </div>
        <div class="section">        </div>
        <div class="section">        </div>
        <div class="section">        </div>
        <div class="section">        </div>
        <div class="section">        </div>

        <ul class="guide">
            <li><b></b><span class="indicator">Section 1 <b></b></span></li>
            <li><b></b><span class="indicator">Section 2 <b></b></span></li>
            <li><b></b><span class="indicator">Section 3 <b></b></span></li>
            <li><b></b><span class="indicator">Section 4 <b></b></span></li>
            <li><b></b><span class="indicator">Section 5 <b></b></span></li>
            <li><b></b><span class="indicator">Section 6 <b></b></span></li>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //I'd measure this in JQuery, but do it mathematically here:
            //Calculate the midpoints of all of the sections.
            var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
            var sectiontops = [];
            
            function updateSectionTops() {
                sectiontops = [];
                var y = 10; //top body margin is 10
                for (var s=0; s<sections.length; s++) {
                    var h = sections[s].offsetHeight;
                    sectiontops.push(y);
                    y+=h;
                }
            }

            var indicators = document.getElementsByClassName('indicator');

            function updateIndicators() {
                for (var i = 0; i < indicators.length; i++) {
                    indicators[i].style.opacity = 0;
                }
                var ls = 0;
                for (var s = 0; s < sections.length; s++) {
                    if (sectiontops[s] > clientmid) break;
                    ls = s;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i <= ls; i++) {
                    indicators[i].style.opacity = 1;
                }
                
            }

            var clientmid = 0;
            function updateClientMid() {
                var height = window.innerHeight
                    || document.documentElement.clientHeight
                    || document.body.clientHeight;
                clientmid = window.scrollY + (height / 2);
                updateSectionTops();
                updateIndicators();
            }
            updateClientMid();

            window.onscroll = updateClientMid;
            window.onresize = updateClientMid;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mark. With midline, are you suggesting I imagine vertical centre of the viewport and work of that? I've tried various things, even sketching what the functionality should be on a sheet of paper and I haven't been able to completely solve the problems yet.

Comment: Presuming that your main scroll direction is vertical, then the distance between the midpoint of your idea of the viewport (a horizontal line Y-Value etc.) and the midline of your section rectangle identifies the closest section. If your scroll is horizontal, then you're looking at vertical midlines. If both, then you may use dx*dx+dy*dy, dx and dy being the differences between vertical and horizontal midlines.

Comment: My apologies. Yes, I meant horizontal (midline) with a vertical scroll. Horizontal scrolling isn't really necessary with this plugin. Thanks for your suggestions though. But they don't really help me much, because what you're suggesting I've already implemented. Basically, when the section scrolls into view, it gets a class 'active', which in turn dynamically adds the 'active' class to the dot. I'm struggling with the rest, what I essentially described in the original question.

Comment: For the dots - just turn them all off, then turn on the ones that you want based on your calculation. For the bar, you still need an idea of the viewport rect. The % height of the bar is the height of the view rectangle over the height of the body. If it's a thumbtrack, the top is the top of the viewport over the body height. Multiply your ratios by your widget/scrollbar height and you have your answer.

If you want to latch to sections, you divide by sectioncount as you are now, do Math.floor and then multiply back up, otherwise, the percentage changes based on the number of sections.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'll sketch it out again in a couple hours. I don't know if this is the right place to ask: but if I get stuck, can you help me privately (or on here)? Paid of course!

Comment: I think you'll suss it with a couple more drawings. You've already done clipping calculations, just check them over in light of what we've discussed.

Comment: Hi Mark. I'm really struggling with this. Actually been trying to solve the above problems for a few weeks now and starting to pull my hair out. Being on a deadline doesn't help either ;). Can we talk privately, on Skype or something? Would help a lot I think. Either way, thanks for your ideas so far!

Comment: @nfq I added a bit of a demo. Didn't do a scrollbar like 'bar', but grew it out of the tooltip type text.

Comment: I just realised that if the sections are small, like 3rd of a screen height, then it doesn't work - actually requires sections to be almost screen size. You can cater for small sections by comparing top of section with bottom of viewport.

Comment: thank you for your demo, it's brilliant. Starting to implement it now, will let you know how it goes! I owe you one mate!

Is 'y' generally meant to be a top offset, for instance if we're using a header or so? What is 'ls' and 's'? I understand what you're doing there, but more trying to understand your perspective.

Comment: Also, huge kudos for the Vanilla JS solution!

Comment: 'y' is just a holder for the vertical position as we track through the document. you need to account for space above first section and between sections manually. With jQuery, you could just getOffset.'ls' is last section as in last section seen above the midline. s could be section_index if you like descriptive parameters (which is good).